# how to build a guidance after the launchScreen?

Tags: ios

I want to build a SrcollViewController which has some imageView as a guide view after the launchScreen done. In appDelegate ,i want to use window.rootViewController. But the project is using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels),window.rootViewController has been used. And it seem hard to change this.Is there any other way to insert a viewController between the launchScreen and JASidePanels?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to present it as a modal viewcontroller over the rootViewController

Comment: This should be a comment.